# texture movement stutters

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es2

Hey I at the moment I have got my texture to move however it stutters as I increment by 0.001 every second.  My animation is done via FPS if that make sense and here is some code

```
FrameCount++;

p_Time = c_Time;
c_Time = PVRShellGetTime();

elapsed = c_Time / 1000.0f;
DT = ((float)(c_Time - p_Time)) / 1000.0f;

fCount += DT;

if(fCount >= 1.0f) //if time is over 1 second reset counters and recount
{
    FPS = FrameCount;
    FrameCount = 0;
    fCount = 0;
    move += 0.001;
    glUniform1f(m_ShaderProgram.auiLoc[eTime], move);
}
```

My problem is I want it to move more seamlessly and not sure how to achieve this and thought I would get some ideas from you.

Oh and here is my vertex and fragment shader

Vert

```
    attribute highp   vec3  inVertex;
attribute mediump vec3  inNormal;
attribute mediump vec2  inTexCoord;
attribute mediump vec3  inTangent;

uniform highp   mat4  MVPMatrix;
uniform mediump vec3  EyePos;
uniform mediump float Time;

varying mediump vec3  EyeDir;
varying mediump vec2  TexCoord;
varying mediump vec2  TexCoord2;
varying mediump float vTime;

void main()
{
    // Transform position
    gl_Position = MVPMatrix * vec4(inVertex,1.0);   

    /*mediump vec2 waterCoord = inTexCoord;
    TexCoord = waterCoord.xy * waterSX; 
    TexCoord += watermovementX;*/
    TexCoord = inTexCoord;
    vTime = Time; 
}
```

and here is my frag

```
    uniform sampler2D  n_mapTex;
uniform sampler2D  n_mapTex2;

varying mediump vec2  TexCoord;
varying mediump vec2  TexCoord2;
varying mediump float vTime;

void main()
{   
    gl_FragColor =  texture2D(n_mapTex, vec2(TexCoord.x + vTime, TexCoord.y + vTime));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Before I get into your code, are you sure that your textures are not too big on filesize?

Comment: hey IMX I solved the problem its because in my code it only adds 0.001 every second rather than on every frame

Answer (score 2):

As you already have a delta time in seconds, and also the 'speed' of the texture in whatever units you use per second, then you simply need to move the texture by the speed (0.001) multiplied by the delta in seconds. Say if you have a delta of 0.5 seconds, the movement would be 0.0005, which is what you want.

To implement it in your program, change

```
if(fCount >= 1.0f) //if time is over 1 second reset counters and recount
{
    FPS = FrameCount;
    FrameCount = 0;
    fCount = 0;
    move += 0.001;
    glUniform1f(m_ShaderProgram.auiLoc[eTime], move);
}
```

to

```
if(fCount >= 1.0f) //if time is over 1 second reset counters and recount
{
    FPS = FrameCount;
    FrameCount = 0;
    fCount = 0;
    glUniform1f(m_ShaderProgram.auiLoc[eTime], move);
}
move += 0.001 * DT
```

This technique is invaluable in developing games which cope with changing framerates, because your objects will always move the same distance *per second* rather than *per frame*, which means you no longer need to assume a constant framerate.

EDIT: As you mentioned the 0.001 was supposed to be per frame, you can simply swap 0.001 in the code for what ever per-second value you desire.